# How to extend a CollectionView's filter?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a class that represents a collection and implements, amongst others, the following interfaces:

- `IEnumerable` so that I can bind a WPF `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to it.
- `ICollectionViewFactory` to use a view I can configure instead of creating a default view

So far, all is fine: I can bind a control, including sorting, filtering and even "live shaping".

**First question**: Due to the `ICollectionViewFactory` the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` is never called (by the UI), but it still appears to be required. **Should I be smelling something here?**

Then, I have one specific scenario where I want to do some additional filtering and the criteria will depend on the render context which is why I thought I'd use an `IValueConverter` with something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var cv = (ICollectionViewFactory)value.CreateView();
    cv.ExtendFilter(i => i.AdditionalFilterProperty);

    return cv;
}
```

The `ExtendFilter` extension method looks like this:

```
public static void ExtendFilter(this ICollectionView view, Predicate<object> filter)
{
    if (view.Filter == null)
    {
        view.Filter = filter;
    }
    else
    {
        var originalFilter = view.Filter;
        view.Filter = item => originalFilter(item) && filter(item);
    }
}
```

**Second question**: Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking, maybe, expression trees...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is correct that `IEnumerable` isnt called if your collection class implements `ICollectionViewFactory`.
Deep in the WPF framework the `ItemsSource` (`IEnumerable`) has its default collection view created. In that code, if the collection already implements `ICollectionViewFactory` then it takes `CreateView` as the actual items source. If it doesnt implement it then it creates a default view with the `IEnumerable` as the items source.

Secondly, your composite filter logic seems reasonable. Expression trees take a lot more implementing, but would also provide a good solution also. Personally I would stick with what you have